# Pandas: 2 columns to key value pair

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 10 columns. The want to create a new column with column 9 as key and column 10 as value.

I tried something like this:

```
df[11]={df[9] :df[10]}
```

I got a Typeerror saying 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Is there any way to go about this?

Column 8 contains session number which may be repeated in other rows.  I need the other columns so that I can put all the key values of 1 session together in 1 row.

Comment: 1) you can't treat a dataframe as a function, so no `()`. 2) if `9` is your column name, then you can do `df[9]`, else you might need `df.loc[:,9]` to access the **10th** column. 3) finally, I'm not sure what you are trying to create.

Comment: I'm sorry. The bracket is a typo error. 9 is my column name because there was no header. I'm trying to put group my item  in column 9 and count in column 10. Column 8 is a session number and may be repeated in other rows and I want to put all the key value into 1 session number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
df[11] = [{k:v} for k, v in df.iloc[:,[9,10]].values]
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 11))
df[[9,10]]

          9     10
0   -0.1223 0.6870
1   -0.1447 0.4517

df[11] = [{k:v} for k, v in df.iloc[:,[9,10]].values]
df[11]

0    {-0.12231839342645735: 0.6869982955094028}
1    {-0.14465311502679143: 0.4516671951915512}
Name: 11, dtype: object
```